# How to import a module outside of the src directory in NextJS?

Tags: web, next.js, frontend

I'm trying to import a module which is located outside of the source directory. So, I tried to add this module to the package.json manually:

`"pdfFile": "file:c:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\js tut"`

Then, I'd yarn-installed in order to make sure that it's been installed already. However, whenever I try to install this module, it sends me this message: module-not-found

```
import {pdf} from 'pdfFile/1377.pdf'
```

I believe this error exists as the application cannot find this module in the applications dependencies. So, is there a way to puzzle out this crux?

I tried to escape the backslash characters.